# Find a string in a WebBrowser Control and replace it while ignoring case

Tags: vb.net, string, webbrowser-control

I currently have a search that works and highlights the found text by replacing the found text with the found text but wrapped in a span tag for highlighting. Works just fine except for two issues. It is currently case sensitive, and I cannot figure out how to scroll to the first found instance. If the user searches for "nozzle" they need to be able to find "Nozzle". Here is the code I have.

```
Try
    tmrSearch.Stop()
    Try
        If txtSearch.Text.Length <= 3 Then
            If txtSearch.Text <> "" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter longer search terms!")
                txtSearch.Text = String.Empty
            End If
        Else
            Dim searchString As String = txtSearch.Text
            Dim textToSearch As String = wbContent.Document.Body.InnerHtml

            textToSearch = textToSearch.Replace(searchString, "<span style=""background-color:yellow"">" & searchString & "</span>")

            If textToSearch.IndexOf(searchString) <> -1 Then
                wbContent.Document.Body.InnerHtml = textToSearch
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(searchString & " is not located in this text!")
            End If

            txtSearch.Text = String.Empty
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter search terms!")
        logger.WriteLog("Error Message : " & ex.Message)
    End Try
Catch ex As Exception
    logger.WriteLog("frmContent : tmrSearch_Tick() : FAILED")
    logger.WriteLog("Error Message : " & ex.Message)
End Try
```

I know the `.Replace()` is case sensitive so I thought I would force the `textToSearch` to lower but then when I put it back, all the text in the Web browser control will be lowercase.  That doesn't suit my needs here.  Any suggestions here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you could try splitting a lower case innertext to find where your search string exists. Then use the lengths of strings from the split to rebuild your innerText from the original case copy. You will need to import system.text to use stringbuilder.

```
Else
    Dim searchString As String = txtSearch.Text

    Dim textOriginal As String = wbContent.Document.Body.InnerHtml
    Dim textToLower As String = wbContent.Document.Body.InnerHtml.ToLower()

    Dim textPieces() as String = textToLower.Split(New String() {searchString}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    Dim i as integer = 0
    Dim strNewInnerHtml as New StringBuilder

    For each strPiece as String In textPieces
        strNewInnerHtml.append(textOriginal.Substring(i,strPiece.Length)
        strNewInnerHtml.append("<span style=""background-color:yellow"">" & searchString & "</span>")
        i += strPiece.Length + searchString.Length
    Next

        If textToLower.IndexOf(searchString) <> -1 Then
            wbContent.Document.Body.InnerHtml = strNewInnerHtml.ToString()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(searchString & " is not located in this text!")
        End If

        txtSearch.Text = String.Empty
   End If
```

Comment: I get an error on the variable searchString inside the split. It says Argument matching parameter 'separator' narrows from 'String' to '1-dimensional array of char'

Comment: I put New String() {searchString} in place of just searchString and the error goes away.  This all works close to 100% but it now puts the highlighted word in front of the searched word. So if I search for work, and it finds it, it replaces work with workwork.

Comment: @xRuhRohx i may have misread the documentation on the split, you must need to provide an array

Comment: @xRuhRohx I've fixed the code, (the integer i now adds on the searchString length) and i think that'll fix the duplication problem

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I appreciate the help and this certainly did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.Replace(...) extension method, the following is a sample C# code (VB code version is in P.S. of this posting):

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace StringClassExtensions
{
    public static class StringReplaceExtension
    {
        public static string Replace(this string str,
                                     string oldValue, string newValue,
                                     StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            const int maxCapacity = 16777215;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return str;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue)) return str;
            if (oldValue == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("oldValue");
            if (oldValue.Length == 0) return str;
            if (str.Length > maxCapacity) throw new ArgumentException("'str' is too long");
            if (oldValue.Length > maxCapacity) throw new ArgumentException("'oldValue' is too long");
            if (newValue.Length > maxCapacity) throw new ArgumentException("'newValue' is too long");

            int currentSearchPosition, lastSearchStartPosition = 0;
            var returnValue = new StringBuilder(str.Length, maxCapacity);

            while ((currentSearchPosition = str.IndexOf(oldValue, lastSearchStartPosition, comparisonType)) >= 0)
            {
                if (currentSearchPosition >= lastSearchStartPosition)
                    returnValue.Append(str.Substring(lastSearchStartPosition, currentSearchPosition - lastSearchStartPosition) + newValue);
                lastSearchStartPosition = currentSearchPosition + oldValue.Length;
            }

            if (lastSearchStartPosition == 0) return str;
            if (lastSearchStartPosition < str.Length)
                returnValue.Append(str.Substring(lastSearchStartPosition));

            return returnValue.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

and edit just one line of your original code:

```
textToSearch = textToSearch.Replace(searchString, "<span style=""background-color:yellow"">" & searchString & "</span>")
```

to

```
textToSearch = textToSearch.Replace(searchString, 
   "<span style=""background-color:yellow"">" & searchString + "</span>",
    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Note: Original string.Replace(...) method's code is published on [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs#69fc1d0aa6df8a90) and AFAIS it uses effective internal implementation - use posted here extension method only when original method isn't suitable.

P.S. Here is VB version of my sample String.Replace(...) method. I have got VB version by automatic conversion on [developerFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=ac1f440b-9601-425f-a05d-3a3a3366018e) and then I edited conversion result VB code manually and briefly tested. It seems to work well.

```
Imports System.Text

Namespace StringClassExtensions
    Public Module StringReplaceExtension
        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
        Public Function Replace(str As String, oldValue As String, newValue As String, comparisonType As StringComparison) As String
            Const maxCapacity As Integer = 16777215
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) Then
                Return str
            End If
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue) Then
                Return str
            End If
            If oldValue Is Nothing Then
                Throw New ArgumentNullException("oldValue")
            End If
            If oldValue.Length = 0 Then
                Return str
            End If
            If str.Length > maxCapacity Then
                Throw New ArgumentException("'str' is too long")
            End If
            If oldValue.Length > maxCapacity Then
                Throw New ArgumentException("'oldValue' is too long")
            End If
            If newValue.Length > maxCapacity Then
                Throw New ArgumentException("'newValue' is too long")
            End If

            Dim currentSearchPosition As Integer, lastSearchStartPosition As Integer = 0
            Dim returnValue = New StringBuilder(str.Length, maxCapacity)

            While (InlineAssignHelper(currentSearchPosition, str.IndexOf(oldValue, lastSearchStartPosition, comparisonType))) >= 0
                If currentSearchPosition >= lastSearchStartPosition Then
                    returnValue.Append(str.Substring(lastSearchStartPosition, currentSearchPosition - lastSearchStartPosition) & newValue)
                End If
                lastSearchStartPosition = currentSearchPosition + oldValue.Length
            End While

            If lastSearchStartPosition = 0 Then
                Return str
            End If
            If lastSearchStartPosition < str.Length Then
                returnValue.Append(str.Substring(lastSearchStartPosition))
            End If

            Return returnValue.ToString()
        End Function
        Private Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, value As T) As T
            target = value
            Return value
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

P.P.S. Test suite for string.Replace(...) method extension

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;
using StringClassExtensions;

namespace Unit_Tests_CS_ConsoleApplication1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Test_0001_StringReplaceMethodExtensionTests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void TestSetup()
        { }
        [TearDown]
        public void TestTearDown()
        { }

        [Test]
        public void TestNullSourceString()
        {
            string testStr = null;
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Assert.IsNull(resultStr);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestEmptySourceString()
        {
            string testStr = string.Empty;
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Assert.IsEmpty(resultStr);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestNullNewValue()
        {
            string testStr = "Hello, World!";
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", null, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Assert.IsTrue(resultStr == testStr);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestEmptyNewValue()
        {
            string testStr = "Hello, World!";
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", string.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Assert.IsTrue(resultStr == testStr);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestNullOldValue()
        {
            Assert.Throws(typeof(ArgumentNullException),
                () =>
                {
                    string testStr = "Hello, World!";
                    string resultStr = testStr.Replace(null, "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                }
                );
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestEmptyOldValue()
        {
            string testStr = "Hello, World!";
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace(string.Empty, "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Assert.IsTrue(resultStr == testStr);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestOldValueIsMissingInTheSearchStr()
        {
            string testStr = "Hello, World!";
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Assert.IsTrue(resultStr == testStr);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestSearchStrEqualsToOldValue()
        {
            string testStr = "oldValue";
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Assert.IsTrue(resultStr == "newValue");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestSearchStrStartsWithOldValue()
        {
            string testStr = "oldValue + some words";
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Assert.IsTrue(resultStr == "newValue + some words");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestSearchStrEndsWithOldValue()
        {
            string testStr = "some words + oldValue";
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Assert.IsTrue(resultStr == "some words + newValue");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestSearchStrHasSeveralOccurrencesOfOldValueSeparatedByOtherChars()
        {
            string testStr = "some words + oldValue + some more words + oldValue + even more words";
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Assert.IsTrue(resultStr == "some words + newValue + some more words + newValue + even more words");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestSearchStrHasSeveralOccurrencesOfOldValueFollowingOneAfterAnother()
        {
            string testStr = "some words + oldValueoldValueoldValue + even more words";
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Assert.IsTrue(resultStr == "some words + newValuenewValuenewValue + even more words");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestCaseInsensitiveStringComparison()
        {
            string testStr = "some words + oldValue + OldValue + oldValue + even more words";
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            Assert.IsTrue(resultStr == "some words + newValue + newValue + newValue + even more words");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestCaseSensitiveStringComparison()
        {
            string testStr = "some words + oldValue + OldValue + oldValue + even more words";
            string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
            Assert.IsTrue(resultStr == "some words + newValue + OldValue + newValue + even more words");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestSourceStringIsOutOfMaxCapacity()
        {
            Assert.Throws(typeof(ArgumentException),
                () =>
                {
                    int testCapacity = new StringBuilder().MaxCapacity / 128 + 1;
                    string testStr = new string('A', testCapacity); 
                    string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                }
                );
        }


        [Test]
        public void TestOldValueIsOutOfMaxCapacity()
        {
            Assert.Throws(typeof(ArgumentException),
                () =>
                {
                    int testCapacity = new StringBuilder().MaxCapacity / 128 + 1;
                    string testStr = "Hello, World!";
                    string oldValue = new string('A', testCapacity);
                    string resultStr = testStr.Replace(oldValue, "newValue", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                }
                );
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestNewValueIsOutOfMaxCapacity()
        {
            Assert.Throws(typeof(ArgumentException),
                () =>
                {
                    int testCapacity = new StringBuilder().MaxCapacity / 128 + 1;
                    string testStr = "Hello, World!";
                    string newValue = new string('A', testCapacity);
                    string resultStr = testStr.Replace("oldValue", newValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                }
                );
        }


        [Test]
        public void TestResultStringIsOutOfMaxCapacity()
        {
            Assert.Throws(typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException),
                () =>
                {
                    string oldValue = "Hello, World!";
                    int testCapacity = new StringBuilder().MaxCapacity / 128 - oldValue.Length;
                    string testStr = oldValue + new string('A', testCapacity);
                    string newValue = "Hello, the New World!";
                    string resultStr = testStr.Replace(oldValue, newValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing text will not work instead you just place the span tags before and after the searched text. This may need changes as follows.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted
    Dim doc2 As mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 = WebBrowser.Document.DomDocument
    Dim ReplacementTag As String = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'>"
    Dim strBuilder As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(doc2.body.outerHTML)
    Dim HTMLString As String = strBuilder.ToString()
    If Me.m_NoteType = ExtractionNoteType.SearchResult Then
        Dim SearchWords As New List(Of String)
        SearchWords.AddRange(Me.txtSearch.Text.Trim.Split(" "))
        For Each item As String In SearchWords
            Dim index As Integer = HTMLString.IndexOf(item, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            ''If index > 0 Then
            While (index > 0 AndAlso index < HTMLString.Length)
                HTMLString = HTMLString.Insert(index, ReplacementTag)
                HTMLString = HTMLString.Insert(index + item.Length + ReplacementTag.Length, "</span>")
                index = HTMLString.IndexOf(item, index + item.Length + ReplacementTag.Length + 7, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            End While
            ''End If
            ''strBuilder.Replace(item, "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'>" + item + "</span>")
        Next
    Else
        ''strBuilder.Replace("<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'>", "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);'>")
    End If
    doc2.body.innerHTML = HTMLString
End Sub
```